# Spacetime diagram

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, geometry

I need your help. I've just begun learning about space time diagrams. Below is my doubt:

An event is shown as a point on a spacetime diagram.

[image]

Another frame  has coordinates of space and time as:

$$\begin{aligned} c t^{\prime} &=(\cosh \theta)(c t)-(\sinh \theta) x \\ x^{\prime} &=(-\sinh \theta)(c t)+(\cosh \theta) x \\ y^{\prime} &=y \\ z^{\prime} &=z \end{aligned}$$
It's said that the new spacetime diagram could be drawn on the previous spacetime diagram as shown below:

[image]

Then is that the time coordinate of the event in the new frame can be found as shown below (red line is parallel to the $x'$ line, $(a, b)$ is the intersection point of red line with $ct'$ axis)

[image]

Hence the new time coordinate is $c t^{\prime}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ *?* Is that correct?

Comment: Not it is wrong, you can not use Pythagoras in this diagram. imagine a=1 what would b be since the x' system moves with v.

Comment: Related : Your identical closed post here [Angle in a spacetime diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728994/angle-in-a-spacetime-diagram?noredirect=1).