# Angle in a spacetime diagram

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, geometry

[image]

> FIGURE 4.13 A Lorentz boost as a change of coordinates on a spacetime diagram. The figure shows the grid of $\left(c t^{\prime}, x^{\prime}\right)$ coordinates defined by $(4.18)$ plotted on a $(c t, x)$ spacetime diagram. The $\left(c t^{\prime}, x^{\prime}\right)$ coordinates are not orthogonal to each other in the Euclidean geometry of the printed page. But they are orthogonal in the geometry of spacetime. (Recall the analogies between spacetime diagrams and maps discussed in Example 4.1.) The $\left(c t^{\prime}, x^{\prime}\right)$ axes have to be as orthogonal as the $(c t, x)$ axes because there is no physical distinction between one inertial frame and another. The orthogonality is explicitly verified in Example 5.2. The hyperbolic angle $\theta$ is a measure of the velocity between the two frames.

The transformation is given as

> $\begin{aligned} c t^{\prime} &=(\cosh \theta)(c t)-(\sinh \theta) x \\ x^{\prime} &=(-\sinh \theta)(c t)+(\cosh \theta) x \\ y^{\prime} &=y \\ z^{\prime} &=z \end{aligned}$

To find the angle $x'$ axes makes with $x$ axes I use

$0=(\cosh \theta)(c t)-(\sinh \theta) x$ to get its slope as $\tanh{\theta}$ and hence the angle is ${\tan}^{-1}(\tanh{\theta})$ but the book says the angle is $\theta$? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Related : Your identical post here [Spacetime diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728944/spacetime-diagram).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @benrg says, the "Minkowskian-angle" (called "rapidity") uses the
hyperbolic functions, and not the circular functions.
With velocity $(v/c)=\tanh\theta$, we have
time-dilation factor $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}=\cosh\theta$ and
Doppler factor $k=\sqrt{\frac{1+(v/c)}{1-(v/c)}}=\exp\theta$.

Geometrically, an angle (a circular angle)
is the arc-length of a circular arc divided by its radius.
For Minkowski spacetime, the Minkowskian-angle
is the Minkowski-arc-length of a Minkowski-circular-arc (a "hyperbolic arc") divided by its Minkowski-radius.

Alternatively, we can characterize an angle
as the twice the area of a circular sector, divided by the square-of-the-radius.
Similarly,
we can characterize a Minkowski-angle (the rapidity)
as the twice the area of a hyperbolic sector, divided by the square-of-the-Minkowski-radius.

Because of these characterizations,
for relativity, one should really draw **a hyperbolic-arc** for the rapidity,
and not a circular-arc, as you have drawn.

Comment: Thank you it is getting clearer.  Is it that all the points on the $x'$ line have the same hyperbolic angle, $\theta$ ?

Comment: @Kashmiri Yes, all of the events on the $x'$-axis are on the line with slope $ct=x\tanh\theta$. Personally, I would reserve "rapidity" to refer to the angular-like measure between timelike lines. The indicated quantity between these spacelike-lines which are coplanar with the 4-velocities are numerically equal to the rapidity in Minkowski spacetime (but not in a Galilean spacetime).

Answer (score 4):

The books is talking about [hyperbolic angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_angle), which are different from ordinary (circular) angles. The math is similar but uses hyperbolic trig functions. The slope of the line is $\tanh θ$ as you said, but the corresponding hyperbolic angle is $\tanh^{-1} \tanh θ = θ$.

The angle on the piece of paper is $\tan^{-1} \tanh θ$, but that has no geometric meaning in this context. It isn't preserved by Lorentz boosts, while the hyperbolic angle is.

Comment: Thank you benrg. So on the piece of paper the lines $x, x'$ have an angle of ${\tan}^{-1}(\tanh{\theta})$ but in the Minkowski space the angle is $\theta$ ? Is that right?

Comment: @Kashmiri That's right (see the added paragraph).

Comment: Great! Thank you from bottom of my heart sir! :)

Comment: Is it also that the hyperbolic angles of all points on the line $x'$ are same and equal to $\theta$ ?

Comment: Applying a Lorentz boost will slide the (x, t) coordinate on a hyperbola, then won't it's hyperbolic angle change? You said it remains the same. Can you please elaborate on that. Thank you

Comment: @Kashmiri What I mean is that the hyperbolic angle between physical objects is preserved by Lorentz boosts. If the lines $x$ and $x'$ both represent physical phenomena of some sort, then both are affected in the same way by Lorentz transformations, and the angle stays the same. If you boost the $x'$ line but not the $x$ line, then the angle will change. Re your other comment, the angle between the axes is $θ$, and remains $θ$ whichever particular points you choose to measure it. ($\angle AOA'$ in high-school notation, where $A$ and $A'$ are on $x$ and $x'$)